# PHP Concatenation with variables

Tags: php

I need a little help in concatenating my variables in the x's below.

So I already , tried with **curly braces** and **periods** with double quotes but nothing works.

Can you please give me a hand here?

Thanks in advance.

```
$output = shell_exec("crontab -l -u daemon");

file_put_contents('/tmp/crontab.txt', $output.'0 0 x x * curl --silent "localhost/test.php?action=cronFunction&id="'.$id.PHP_EOL);

echo exec('crontab /tmp/crontab.txt');
```

Comment: Please read [ask], in particular where exactly your problems are, like what you expect to have at some point. Make sure you strip all irrelevant code, similar to a [mcve] as well. As a new user, also take the [tour].

Comment: Thank you very much @UlrichEckhardt will do ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
file_put_contents('/tmp/crontab.txt', $output.'0 0 '.$var1.' '.$var2.' * curl --silent "localhost/test.php?action=cronFunction&id="'.$id.PHP_EOL);
```

Replace your x with the $var1 and $var2 values, try playing with strings and you will get hold of it.

Comment: Thank you very much , it worked like a charm ! I'll try to practice my concatenation skills in strings ;)